# Calculate norm of functional in space of sequences with limit 0

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E=c_0$ be the normed space of real sequences with limit 0, and the uniform norm ($\Vert a_n \Vert_0 = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{R}} |a_n|$)

Let $L: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined as
$$L\{a_n\} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{5^n} \quad \forall \{a_n\}\in c_0$$

L is linear (trivial) and continuous:
$$ |L(a_n) | \leq \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{5^n} \right)\Vert a_n \Vert_0 = \frac{1}{4} \Vert a_n \Vert_0$$

Then $\Vert L \Vert_{E'} \leq 1/4$.

How can I prove that $\Vert L \Vert = 1/4$? Does the norm assume (reach) the supremum?

Being $\Vert L\Vert := \sup_{\Vert a_n \Vert = 1} |L(a_n)|$, I'm trying to find elements in $c_0$ with $L(a_n) = 1/4$.

Answer (score 3):

compute the image of these unit vectors $x_{n}$,where $x_{n}^{k}=1,k\leq n$ and zero otherwise,that is $x_{n}^{k}=(1,1,1...,0,0....)$  .In fact the topological dual of $c_{0}$ is isometrically isomorphic to $l^{1}$ and your example is nothing but the linear form corresponding to $\frac{1}{5^{n}}$ which is an element of $l^{1}$ and the result u wanna prove is the fact that the corresponding form has the same norm as absolutely convergent sequence $\frac{1}{5^{n}}$ .
Now let $(a_{n})$ be a unit vector,i.e $\sup_{n\geq 1}\lvert a_{n} \rvert =1$,then $\lvert L(a_{n}) \rvert \leq \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\lvert a_{n}\rvert }{5^{n}}\leq \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{5^{n}}=\frac{1}{4}$,remark that in order for the equality to it it necessary and sufficient that $\forall n\geq 1, \lvert a_{n} \rvert =1$ but this would contradict the fact that $(a_{n}) \in c_{0}$ ,so there is no unit vector for which the norm is reached.

Comment: I don't see the final contradiction (contradict the fact that $(a_n$) ...)?

Comment: edited ,$\lim_{n\to \infty }a_{n}=0$